# Github credentials in Jenkins Job

Tags: git, github, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am looking for workaround in Jenkins so that I can avoid displaying Github credentials in Jenkins job.Something like below screen.
[image]

Comment: You could use SSH keys for Git access. However to get a status back to GitHub, it will need to store the PAT or password on disk. I'm not sure if Jenkins encrypts the file.

Comment: Why is showing the GitHub credentials (not full password) an issue?

Comment: My client doesn't like credentials details popping out in Jenkins job.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure what you are asking, but you can use Github's [personal access tokens](https://github.com/settings/tokens) to create an access token with limited scopes, for example without write permissions.

This is also useful for when you have 2-Factor-Authentication activated on Github and need to use some software which doesn't support Github's 2FA, like `git` itself.